# How To separate methods from my giant generic class

Tags: c#

So I have a very big Generic class 1500+ rows and growing, with loads of methods. It has CrazyMethods and GoodMethods, I want to put the different kinds of methods in their own class but still be able to use my generic as if they were inside the generic class.

```
public class MyGeneric<T> : IMyGeneric<T> where T : IEntity
{
    public MyGeneric(string stuff)
    {
        moreStuff(stuff);
    }
    // Region Good
    public void MyGoodMethod1(T entity)
    {
      //does good stuff with the generic..
    }
    public T MyGoodMethod2()
    {
      //does other good stuff with the generic..
    }

    //Region Crazy
    public void MyCrazyMethod1(T entity)
    {
      //does crazy stuff with the generic..
    }
    public T MyCrazyMethod2()
    {
      //does other crazy stuff with the generic..
    }
}
```

Now in my other project where I use this generic it looks something like this

```
...
SomeObject _myObject =  new MyGeneric<SomeObject>("ladida");

_myObject.MyGoodMethod1();
//..Other stuff
_myObject.MyCrazyMethod2();¨
...
```

How do I separate the methods from the MyGeneric class into separate classes (MyGenericGoodMethods.cs, MyGenericCrazyMethods.cs) but still be able to use them the way I showcased above ?

If I could use extension methods for generics that would be the perfect solution.

```
public static class MyGenericGoodMethods<T> where T : IEntity
{
    public static T Method2(this MyGeneric<T> generic)
    {
        //does other good stuff with the generic..
    }
}
```

but

> Extension method can only be declared in non generic, non nested, static class

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549029/is-it-possible-to-do-static-partial-classes

Comment: Or just use partials... they wouldn't need to be static

Comment: Thanks, Ill take a look

Answer (score 3):

You can declare extension method in normal static class and use it with generic.

```
public static class MyGenericGoodMethodsExtensions
{
    public static T Method2(this MyGeneric<T> generic)
    {
        //does other good stuff with the generic..
    }
}

var myGeneric = new MyGeneric<string>();
myGeneric.Method2()
```

But you can always split your giant class in many separated generic classes and use them inside your main-generic class.

Split up your interfaces

```
public interface IMyGeneric<T>
{
    void MyGeneric(string stuff);
}

public interface IMyGoodGeneric<T>
{
    void MyGoodMethod1(T entity);
    void MyGoodMethod2(T entity);
}

public interface IMyCrazyGeneric<T>
{
    void MyCrazyMethod1(T entity);
    void MyCrazyMethod2(T entity);
}
```

Introduce separated implementation

```
public class MyGeneric<T> : IMyGeneric<T> where T : IEntity
{
    public void MyGeneric(string stuff)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}

public class MyGoodGeneric<T> : IMyGoodGeneric<T> where T : IEntity
{
    public void MyGoodMethod1(T entity) {}
    public void MyGoodMethod2(T entity) {}
}

public class MyCrazyGeneric<T> : IMyCrazyGeneric<T> where T : IEntity
{
    public void MyCrazyMethod1(T entity) {}
    public void MyCrazyMethod2(T entity) {}
}
```

Then you can create your "giant" composition class which will implement all interfaces and use already existed implementations

```
public class MyGiantGeneric<T> : IMyGeneric<T>,
                                 IMyGoodGeneric<T>,
                                 IMyCrazyGeneric<T> where T : IEntity
{
    private readonly IMyGeneric<T> _myGeneric;
    private readonly IMyGoodGeneric<T> _myGoodGeneric;
    private readonly IMyCrazyGeneric<T> _myCrazyGeneric;

    public MyGiantGeneric(IMyGeneric<T> myGeneric,
                          IMyGoodGeneric<T> myGoodGeneric,
                          IMyGCrazyGeneric<T> myCrazyGeneric)
    {
        _myGeneric = myGeneric;
        _myGoodGeneric = myGoodGeneric;
        _myCrazyGeneric = myCrazyGeneric;
    }

    public void MyGeneric(string stuff)
    {
        _myGeneric.MyGeneric(stuff);
    }

    public void MyGoodMethod1(T entity) 
    {
        _myGoodGeneric.MyGoodMethod1(entity);
    }

    // and so on...
}
```

With this approach your logic will stay in logically separated classes.
In case somewhere you need only `MyGoodGeneric` method you don't need to provide whole giant class and will provide only the part needed.

In case some where you want introduce another implementation only for the `MyCrazy` methods you will not be forced to implement `MyGood` methods which you don't need in this case.

Comment: Interfaces don't expose constructors.

Comment: @kall2sollies - what you mean?

Comment: Thank you for trying Fabio, but I really don't want to create additional interfaces. Partial classes were what I needed. Your solution would still require additional code for every method inside my big generic.

Comment: @user3621898 - I want to answer your question because I noticed you using `regions` which are good sign to separate logic to different classes. Does you have local variables in the class which used for example only for `Crazy` methods? If so the it is another very good sign to separate class. Classes in OO programming are developer's tools and their cannot be more or less.

Comment: @Fabio I though your void MyGeneric(string stuff) method was a constructor signature in the interface, but I read too fast, my bad !

Answer (score 0):

So Partial classes were exactly what i was looking for. Thanks to @BradleyDotNET and @AliAbdelfattah

```
public partial class MyGeneric<T> : IMyGeneric<T> where T : IEntity
{
    public MyGeneric(string stuff)
    {
        moreStuff(stuff);
    }
   //.. other stuff
}
```

in MyGenericGood.cs

```
public partial class MyGeneric<T> where T : IEntity
{
    public void MyGoodMethod1(T entity)
    {
      //does good stuff with the generic..
    }
    public T MyGoodMethod2()
    {
      //does other good stuff with the generic..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension method can be generic, not its container class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T Method2<T>(this MyGeneric<T> generic)
    {
    }
}
```